# Editing a Text Field using Spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext

I wish to edit the edit text box using spinner. If person chooses 1st option I want to add a negative sign at the start of the number. If a person chooses 2nd option, the negative sign should vanish. This is how i tried to do, I get the negative sign, but it does not vanish when I choose the other option:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.vspin:
        if (arg2 == 0) {
            latitudeinput.setText("" + latitudeinput.getText().toString(),
                    TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        } else {
            latitudeinput.setText("-" + latitudeinput.getText().toString(),
                    TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }

        break;
    case R.id.hspin:
        if (arg2 == 0) {
            longitudeinput.setText(
                    "" + longitudeinput.getText().toString(),
                    TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        } else {
            longitudeinput.setText("-"
                    + longitudeinput.getText().toString(),
                    TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the first char in edittext and if it is '-', remove it

```
if (arg2 == 0) {
    if(latitudeinput.getText().toString().length()<1){
         latitudeinput.setText("" + latitudeinput.getText().toString();
         return;
    }
    if(latitudeinput.getText().toString().charAt(1)=='-'){
        latitudeinput.setText("" + latitudeinput.getText().toString().substring(1),
        TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
else{
    latitudeinput.setText("-" + latitudeinput.getText().toString(),
    TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
}
```

Comment: I am getting a Stringoutofboundexception length=0 index=1

Comment: what if i work on the alternative and try to pass the string of edittext with a negative sign to the next acitivty by implementing the following code: data1 = longitudeinput.getText().toString(); data2 = latitudeinput.getText().toString();
if (spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("North"){
dat1 = Double.parseDouble(data1) * -1;} //and then dat1 is passed to the next activity
but this isnt working too

Comment: Its giving the negative sign, but i am back to where my question is. The negative sign does not vanish when I choose the second option in the spinner

Comment: i have edited again. you should try to understand the logic, rather on relying on my code. I am trying to check if edittext contains '-' and if it does, just trying to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

in your case: R.ID.? use the following code

```
            String s = latitudeinput.getText().toString().trim();
            if (arg2 == 0) {
                if(s.contains("-")){
                    latitudeinput.setText(s.subSequence(1, s.length()),
                        TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                }else{
                    latitudeinput.setText(s.subSequence(1, s,
                        TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                }
            } else {
                if(!s.contains("-")){
                    latitudeinput.setText("-" +s,
                        TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                }else{
                    latitudeinput.setText(s.subSequence(1, s,
                        TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                }
            }
```

Comment: subsequence can only take (int, int), giving an error in the else statement